# Issues with sourcing and overlaying packages

Tags: kinect, catkin, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to overlay a package on my ROS Hydro and in order to not type it in every time, I added it to the .bashrc so that it looks like this:

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source /home/robot2/overlay_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

However, when I try to do a normal roslaunch:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch camera:=kinect_1 device_id:=1@0
```

on openni_launch it gives the following message:

```
multiple files named [openni.launch] in package [openni_launch]:
- /opt/ros/groovy/share/openni_launch/launch/openni.launch
- /opt/ros/hydro/share/openni_launch/launch/openni.launch
Please specify full path instead
```

The thing is, the only ROS package being sourced should be a camera_pose package.  It doesn't have to do with the openni launching. I'm not sure why Groovy is being pulled in.  I have it installed but not sourced or on package path at all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118721/issues-with-sourcing-and-overlaying-packages/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-01-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-07-17**:
Can you update your question with the output of something like `env | grep ROS`? Without enough info, I can only assume that ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or else is messed up somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Clear the devel and build folder (along with hidden files) and do a catkin_make again.  The devel/.catkin and build/.project files at times have details of other workspaces for some reason.

---

Originally posted by [vinmean](https://answers.ros.org/users/27224/vinmean/) with karma: 76 on 2017-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0